# Fade two images as background-image using css

Tags: css

In your opinion, what is the best way to merge two different images making a "fade" effect using css.

For example this is the effect that I want to create.

[image]

Imagine that we have two images, one is this vanilla color and another is the coffee image.

The first thing I put one by side with div, but I do not know how can I create this effect. Anyone have an idea how can I do that?

Here I created a Codepen for that, you can see that I have one image that is blue, and I want to create the same effect in the right image:
https://codepen.io/fernandocacavaio/pen/vYKEXPo

```
    <html>
        <head></head>
         <body>
            <div style="width: 100%;">
                <div class="left"> 
                    Left Div 
                </div>
                <div class="right"> 
                    Right Div
                </div>
            </div>
         </body>
        </html>

.left {
        width: 50%;
        height: 350px;
        float: left;
        background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/7SKNPWz/blue-background.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%;
    }


.right {
        height: 350px;
        background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/SfnB3hs/Capture.jpg');
    }
}
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60971741/8620333

Comment: last snippet here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47532043/8620333